# Pass character argument to data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How to pass character argument to data.table? I've tried `eval` but it didn't help:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(iris)

groupedBy <- "Species"

dt[,.(m = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = .(groupedBy)] # error!
```

Comment: Use `c` i.e. `dt[,.(m = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = c(groupedBy)] ` or if there is only one variable, you can just do `dt[,.(m = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = groupedBy]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can directly pass it without the `.()`

```
dt[,.(m = mean(Sepal.Length)), by = groupedBy]
```

It also works for multiple columns

```
grpby <- c('cyl', 'gear')
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(m_mpg = mean(mpg)), by = grpby]
```

Comment: and you need to use get() if you want to use conditions on the i

Comment: @denis You also use `eval(as.name`